# How to use do while function but also not stop other codes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to fix this problem where if you use do and while code, it will stop other commands, but if it is done, then it will continue those commands.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    std::cout << "hey";
    Sleep(1000);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    std::cout << "hey number 2";
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

it is supposed to output together

> hey

> hey number 2

but instead it's just

> hey

and then once it's done it's just

> hey number 2

Comment: I'm struggling to follow your description of the problem. Can you please include a [mcve] and your exact output (maybe make the loop much smaller for that)?

Comment: you need to read about multithreading. Multithreading is not easy and I am not sure if you would really benefit from a very short introduction to it that one could give in an answer here.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

Comment: Combine the 2 `for` loops?

Comment: Please tell us what exactly you expect the output to look like. In the code there are 2 loops printing something but that does not match your "expected output"

Comment: Pls rephrase the question properly. I couldn't figure out what you are asking.
If you need 2 loops to be executed parallelly, you can use multi-threading
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthreads

Comment: @EbinXavier why would you recommend pthreads when there is `std::thread` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need threads.

Take this example. It should do the trick

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <synchapi.h>

using namespace std;

void fun1() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
        std::cout << "Hey";
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

void fun2() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++) {
        std::cout << "Hey you too";
        Sleep(630);
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::thread first(fun1);
    std::thread second(fun2);

    first.join();
    second.join();

    std::cout << "done";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just one loop that prints `"Heyhey number 2"`? That seems to fit OP:s description and it's much simpler.

Comment: I'd prefer `std::async` over raw threads.

Comment: @sweenish AFAIK only on windows with MSCV runtime std::async uses a threadpool. So on most platforms there is no gain or loss either way and both std::async with std::launch::async and std::thread are equivalent

Comment: @PKramer I actually don't care about that. I prefer the syntax of `std::async` over a raw thread. If we hate raw pointers and C-arrays so much, the same belief should extend to other abstractions offered by the language.

Comment: @sweenish A very valid point. I agree, std::async better describes what you want and thread is much more the how.